# ICMP TTL exceeded replies with destination IP from NAT router

Tags: linux-networking, nat, icmp, nftables

I'm playing with nftables and observe strange behaviour which I cannot explain.

I have three VMs, `source`, `router` and `destination`. All run latest Oracle EL 8.5 and are configured via nft.

- `source` has single network interface `enp0s8` with IP 10.111.111.1 in /24 subnet.
- `router` has two network interfaces: `enp0s8` with IP 10.111.111.2 in /24 subnet, and `enp0s9` with IP 10.100.100.2 in /24 subnet.
- `destination` has single network interface `enp0s8` with IP 10.100.100.1 in /24 subnet.

My goal is to have `destination` hidden from `source` behind NAT, with IP 10.200.200.1. What I've done:

1. Enabled IP routing on `router`.
2. Blocked direct access from 10.111.111.0/24 to 10.100.100.0/24 on `router`.
3. Added static route 10.200.200.0/24 via 10.111.111.2 (`router`) on `source`.
4. Configured NAT on `router` as follows:

```
        chain prerouting {
                type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat; policy accept;
                iifname "enp0s8" ip daddr 10.200.200.1 dnat to 10.100.100.1
        }

        chain postrouting {
                type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
                ip saddr 10.100.100.1 oifname "enp0s8" snat to 10.200.200.1
        }
```

Everything works as expected, `destination` is reachable from `source` only as 10.200.200.1 and not as 10.100.100.1 (sure, I know it's bad to work under root, it's just experimental VMs):

```
[root@source ~]# ping 10.100.100.1
PING 10.100.100.1 (10.100.100.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 10.100.100.1 ping statistics ---
15 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 14320ms

[root@source ~]# ping 10.200.200.1
PING 10.200.200.1 (10.200.200.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.200.200.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.554 ms
64 bytes from 10.200.200.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=1.80 ms
64 bytes from 10.200.200.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=1.84 ms
^C
--- 10.200.200.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2043ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.554/1.397/1.836/0.598 ms
```

But when I do traceroute, or send ping with TTL=1, reply has the IP 10.200.200.1, instead of the `router`'s IP 10.111.111.2:

```
[root@source ~]# traceroute 10.200.200.1
traceroute to 10.200.200.1 (10.200.200.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.200.200.1 (10.200.200.1)  0.752 ms  0.679 ms  0.984 ms
 2  10.200.200.1 (10.200.200.1)  1.181 ms  1.130 ms  1.070 ms
[root@source ~]# ping 10.200.200.1 -c 1 -t 1
PING 10.200.200.1 (10.200.200.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.200.200.1 icmp_seq=1 Time to live exceeded

--- 10.200.200.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, +1 errors, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

If I do the same for any other address in 10.200.200.0/24 subnet, the replies have correct IPs:

```
[root@source ~]# ping 10.200.200.2 -c 1 -t 1
PING 10.200.200.2 (10.200.200.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.111.111.2 icmp_seq=1 Time to live exceeded

--- 10.200.200.2 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, +1 errors, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

Could anyone please clarify why in the first case ICMP TTL exceeded reply has the IP of the final destination, and in the second case it has the IP of the router?